# Save in an array the data from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In Python, if I have the following file:

```
1  10 
2  50 
3   8
4   9
5  16
6  18
```

How would I save these data - in two arrays - like so?

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
B = [10 50 8 9 16 18]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the `i`-th tuple contains the `i`-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence. When there are multiple arguments which are all of the same length, `zip()` is similar to `map()` with an initial argument of None. With a single sequence argument, it returns a list of 1-tuples. With no arguments, it returns an empty list.

Let me show you by example:

```
In [1]: filedata = """1  10
   ...: 2  50
   ...: 3   8
   ...: 4   9
   ...: 5  16
   ...: 6  18
   ...: """

In [2]: filedata
Out[2]: '1  10 \n2  50 \n3   8\n4   9\n5  16\n6  18\n'

In [3]: data = []
   ...: for line in fdata.splitlines():
   ...:     lineParts  = line.strip().split()
   ...:     data.append(lineParts)
   ...:

In [4]: data
Out[4]: [['1', '10'], ['2', '50'], ['3', '8'], ['4', '9'], ['5', '16'], ['6', '18']]

In [5]: zip(*data)
Out[5]: [('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'), ('10', '50', '8', '9', '16', '18')]
```

Note that we use `*data` instead of `data`, to unpack each element in the list into a separate argument to `zip()`.

Note that now we have a list  of two `tuple()`s, and you wanted `A` and `B` to be lists, so here's how we do that, using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), to change both `tuple()`s to `list()`s:

```
In [15]: (A, B) = map(list, zip(*data))

In [16]: A
Out[16]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

In [17]: B
Out[17]: ['10', '50', '8', '9', '16', '18']
```

**Edit:** For clarity, the complete code is here:

```
filename = 'input.txt'

data = []
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        lineParts  = line.strip().split()
        data.append(lineParts)

(A, B) = map(list, zip(*data))
```

Comment: But  for this : 1  10 
2  50 
3   8
4   9
5  16
6  18                                                                                                                  i have to read this file :/

Comment: I don't understand. That's what I showed above. Are you saying you need to know how to open the file?

Comment: i mean i need to read a text file before to save this in a array where there is the datas

Comment: See my edit at the bottom.  `A` and `B` are your `list()`s ("arrays").

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This pure Python3 code is understandable to a beginner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

first = list()
second = list()

with open("/tmp/tmp.txt", "r") as data:
    for a in data.readlines():
        _1, _2 = a.split()
        first.append(int(_1))
        second.append(int(_2))

print("A =",first,"\nB =",second)
```

And it gives you:

```
$ python3 /tmp/tmp.py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = [10, 50, 8, 9, 16, 18]
```